# GitLab Runner : unable to update URL base from redirection

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-auto-devops

I'm currently experimenting with a problem to set up a GitLab Runner.  First, I can't run my Runner because I can't use the same file with two processes on Windows 10. It means that I have to create a Runner (which start in a "run" state) each time I want to pause my process. I can't use either command like `list` or `run` which make everything hard to debug.

This issue is documented here: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/4691 but it's still very annoying for me

My second issue occurs when I try to run a job. I got an error :

> Fatal : unable to update url base from redirection :
>        asked for http://gitlab-ci-token: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx192.168.XXX.XXX/PoC/Project.git/info/refs?service=git-upload-pack
>     redirect : http://192.168.XXX.XXX:50000/?service=git-upload-pack

I'm guessing that this issue is due to the port configuration, because my GitLab server use port 30000 & 30001, not 5000. Do you know how I can change that port? In an ideal world without having to change my Docker setting (it would take a lot of time to make the IT come :/ )